# VBA: after running the macro, the paste settings are changed to wrong

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I have a macro which merges several columns into one by separating the data with a semicolon (";"). After the macro is finished, I cannot paste the data into a new workbook properly.The only solution is to close absolutely all the workbooks.
I tried to clear copypaste mode, undone macro with column to text, but it's not work as propperly as close and open workbook.I would like to restore the basic settings of excel without closing it.

'''

```
 With wb.Sheets(1).Columns(1)
    .Insert Shift:=xlToRight

For i = 1 To Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
    TempString = ""
    For j = 2 To Range("Z1").End(xlToLeft).Column
        If j <> Range("Z1").End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            TempString = TempString & _
              Cells(i, j).Value & ";"
        Else
            TempString = TempString & _
              Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next
    Cells(i, 1).Value = TempString
Next

Columns("B:D").ClearContents

End With
```

Comment: What result do you get exaclty and why isn't it a proper result?

Comment: The above code does not use ClipBoard. How can you be sure that this is the `guilty` code?

Comment: `I cannot paste the data into a new workbook properly.` What do you mean by this? Also check if the `Data | TextToColumns` has `;` as a delimiter. Because that will interfere when you are pasting data which has `;`

Comment: And if the above is what is interferring then add couple of lines at the end of the code which does the following **1.** selects a blank cell. **2.** Add a temp string to it. **3.** Perform `.TextToColumns` on it with `Semicolon:=False` **4.** Clear the cell **5.** This should reset the `TextToColumns` delimiter.

Comment: You said "The only solution is to close absolutely all the workbook": This indicates the cause is that you're not fully qualifying your ranges.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Thank You but I tried that solution before, but without effect. The data is still pasting as a column, not as a table. Tab-splitting works pretty well, but some lines have tab-separated proper names, and the table is going wird.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're not fully qualifying your ranges. The code in your post will work correctly if and only if the sheet you're changing is the active sheet: This is why when you close all other workbooks, your code works.

Try the following:

```vb
    Dim lLastCol As Long
    
    With wb.Sheets(1)
        .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        lLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        For i = 1 To .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            TempString = ""
            
            For j = 2 To lLastCol
                TempString = TempString & .Cells(i, j).Value
                If j <> lLastCol Then
                    TempString = TempString & ";"
                End If
            Next
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = TempString
        Next
        
        '.Range("B1").Resize(1, lLastCol - 1).EntireColumn.ClearContents
        .Range("B:D").ClearContents
    End With
```

Notice how all occurrences of `.Range` and `.Cells` are preceded by a `.` (try to get in the habit of always preceding `Range` and `Cells` with a qualifying `.`). Also When you repeat things like `Range("Z1").End(xlToLeft).Column` think about stashing the value in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem with copying remains.

Answer (score 0):

From the very beginning and in steps.

1. I have 2 excel file open, one with a macro (macro.xlsm) and one empty (excel2.xlsx)
2. With  the file macro.xlsm I modified the data and save it as .csv (separated by “;”)
3. I closed the macro.xlsm but left the excel2.xlsx file open
4. From an application, I copy table information and paste it  into the excel2.xlsx
5. Information from an application is pasted into one column instead of being pasted as a table
6. If I close all files and open new one, the information will be pasted as a table